# Get the value once modification done on database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, client-server

in my program I have a marquee tag . the speed of the marquee is stored in database table. here I use ajax to get the value of the speed parameter (scrollamount) periodically . the drawback of my code is it check the server continuously whether modification done or not. and also the marquee speed dropped few milliseconds . what is the best way to do this? is Socket solve this problem ?

```
function assignsped () {
    var uid=$("#txtuid").val();
    var getvalue = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/get_user_info.php",
        data: {uid:uid},
        async: false
    }).success(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){assignsped();}, 5000);
    }).responseText;

    document.getElementById('mymarquee').setAttribute('scrollamount', getvalue, 0);

}
```

Comment: I'm curious as to what use case you have that calls for a marquee's speed to be continuously changed during a single page view.

Comment: its a therapist program .